# closure or handler in object?

Tags: javascript

I click a button and there is a handler. I have never understood if I should use a closure, or let the handler be in a object. For example, in HTML I have,

```
<button id="b">Go</button>
<button id="c">Go</button>
```

and in JavaScript (with some jQuery),

```
var hdl=function(){
    var hdl=function(){
        foo+="foo"
        console.log(foo)
    }, 
    foo="" 
    return hdl
}()
$("#b").click(hdl)

var obj={
    bar:"",
    hdl:function(){
        this.bar+="bar"
        console.log(this.bar)
    }
}
var baz=function(){
    obj.hdl()
}
$("#c").click(baz)
```

Both work. Or are there situations in which you can only use one of them?

Comment: Semicolons be damned! I like it.

Comment: You really should be using semicolons (`;`) to mark the end of statements. And you can use whatever you want to. Actually, in both cases you are using closures, you just change the way you organize your data. Use whatever is more suitable.

Answer (score 3):

An event handler is always a function or an object that implements the EventListener interface.  I've never understood any reason to use an EventListener object rather than a function so I've only seen functions used, but you can use either.

If you choose a function, it's up to you whether you want a function to be a global function, an anonymously declared function or a function that is a property of an object.  There is no "right" answer as it depends upon how you want to structure your code.

My event handlers are usually anonymously declared functions just because that's usually how I structure things and generally nothing more is needed.  **Simple is best so you should make it no more complicated than needed.**

A closure is just a function body that survives longer than the simple execution of the function because some other function reference inside is still active.  Whether to use a closure or not depends on your needs and again the structure of your code.  Closures can be really handy ways of keeping some state without using global variables, but other times they aren't needed at all.

Comment: Not true; an event handler is always an `EventListener` object. It's just that browsers are allowed to synthesize an `EventListener` given just the definition of its `handleEvent` method.

Comment: OK, fine, an event listener can be either an object that implements the EventListener interface or a function.  I've never seen anyone write javascript that implements an EventListener object directly, nor have I understood any reason to do so, but if you want to do so, you can.  Answer updated to reflect this.

Comment: I have occasionally found it more convenient to create a prototype event listener which I then create instances of to associate data with the listener, rather than fiddling around with nested scopes.

Comment: @Neil - that's creative.  I can see how that could be useful as you can set instance data on the listener object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up terms.

**Closures are a natural result of JavaScript's scoping rules, not something you choose to create**

The jQuery `click` event **always** takes a function.  Whether that function is attached to an object—thereby making it a method—doesn't really matter.  Depending on how that function is written, it may form a closure that affects you.

A closure is when a function "remembers" the variables in the context in which it's defined.

The classical closure example is something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    $("#button" + i).click(function() { alert("you clicked button " + i); });
```

Most developers are surprised to learn that each button displays 10, which is the value of `i` when the outer scope ends.  This happens because each of those functions declared in the loop has formed a closure over `i`.  Those functions don't just get the value of `i` when they're declared, they get the actual i, in all its glory.  That's why changing `i` after you create the function causes the created function to reflect the updated value of `i`

Situations like this are fixed by **breaking** the closure by passing i to a function, since function parameters are passed by value.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     (function(localI) {
         $("#button" + i).click(function() { alert("you clicked button " + localI); });
     )(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between your cases is that in one of them you are bundling your variables (foo) in an object. The following third example should make this point clear:

```
function hdl(variables){
   variables.foo += variables.foo;
}

var obj = {foo: ""};
var baz = function(){
    hdl(obj);
}
```

I don't think any of these alternatives is in anyway generally superior to the others. You should decide to use whatever solution is simpler and easier to understand and mantain depending on what your particular problem is.

For example, in the version using objects the variables are dinamically bound while in the version with closures they are statically bound. This means that the object version is more extensible (with inheritance, mixins, etc) while the closure version is more rigid (but simpler to reason about at compile time)